# Ядро FreeBSD для Debian

Tags: debian, freebsd

Недавно наткнулся на заметку о том, что есть сборка Debian с ядром FreeBSD. Не совсем понял, зачем это было сделано?

Answer (score 4):

> Не совсем понял, зачем это было сделано?

Опенсурс такой опенсурс. Он предоставляет полную свободу действий. Кому нравится или хочется что-то делать определенным образом, тогда он это и делает. Вот и рождаются проекты вроде Nexenta - ядро Solaris с GNU-окружением. А что? Очень даже полезно. Где я еще нахаляву найду поддержку ZFS? К тому же, GNU-окружение позволяет себя чувствовать одинаково комфортно на разных ОСях.

> Ядро FreeBSD для Debian

Оно - http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/ ?

Конкретно лично для меня основным отличем GNU/kFreeBSD от классического FreeBSD является использование дебиановского менеджера пакетов. Мне лично система портов BSD ближе. Но кому DEB нравится больше. Про прочие причины использование GNU/kFreeBSD можно почитать [тут](http://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD_why)